# Confusion with enum#with_index - starting offset index

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

```
a=[11,22,31,224,44].to_enum
=> #<Enumerator: [11, 22, 31, 224, 44]:each>
a.select.with_index{|x| puts x if x<2 }
=> []
a.with_index(2)
=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [11, 22, 31, 224, 44]:each>:with_index(2)>
irb(main):011:0> a.with_index(2){|x| puts x if x==224}
224
=> [11, 22, 31, 224, 44]
a.with_index(2){|x| puts x if x < 224}
11
22
31
44
=> [11, 22, 31, 224, 44]
```

***Confusion:*** *Here I have set the starting offset as `2`.But the if we look into the output- how `11` comes*
instead of `31`. As the `31` is on the `2th` position.

```
a.with_index(2){|x| puts x if x > 224}
=> [11, 22, 31, 224, 44]
a.with_index(1){|x| puts x if x > 224}
=> [11, 22, 31, 224, 44]
a.with_index(1){|x| puts x if x < 224}
11
22
31
44
=> [11, 22, 31, 224, 44]
a.with_index(1){|x| puts x if x < 224}
11
22
31
44
=> [11, 22, 31, 224, 44]
```

***Confusion:*** *Here bove I have set the starting offset as `1`.But the if we look into the output- how `11` comes instead of `22`. As the `22` is on the `1st` position.*

In considering all the fact together I would like to know even if we mentioned the starting offset - why `enum#with_index` not started the evaluation from mentioned offset?

***Note:*** Is there any direct approach to print the `index` also with the contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Enumerator#with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) has confusing documentation,but hopefully this will make it more clear.

```
a=[11,22,31,224,44].to_enum
=> [11, 22, 31, 224, 44]
a.with_index { |val,index| puts "index: #{index} for #{val}" }
index: 0 for 11
index: 1 for 22
index: 2 for 31
index: 3 for 224
index: 4 for 44

a.with_index(2) { |val,index| puts "index: #{index} for #{val}" }
index: 2 for 11
index: 3 for 22
index: 4 for 31
index: 5 for 224
index: 6 for 44
```

As you can see, what it actually does is offset the index, not start iterating from the given index.

Comment: I also should get up-vote :) as my catch was right,only couldn't prove to myself, but with the help of you I did now.

Comment: Is this a bug to the ruby? otherwise how the original array element gets changed their positions?

Comment: The array elements stay in the same order, they just get a different index value (but still monotonic based on the offset provided). In your original examples notice that since you're not using the index all your code will behave identically if you replace #with_index with #each